# Leaflet bindPopup Coordinates

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

i use Leaflet library for my map and use markerCluster for grouping.
When i click marker, it opens another 2 or more small markers(spider style)
If small markers located in different coordinates, there is no issue.But if the small markers located in same coordinates and when i open popUp it overlaps each other.(it opens the popup on each other)
I want to open popup in different positions or close to each other.Below is part of my code

```
marker.on('click', marker.bindPopup("<dl><dt>Name : " + g. Name 
                                     </dt><dt>SurName : " g. Surname, {permanent:true}   );
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't have any experience with marker clusters, but maybe this plugin also works for overlapping popups: https://github.com/yafred/leaflet-responsive-popup

Comment: You can do it in two ways, if I remember correctly markerCluster, it is possible to turn off the generation of markers in the same place with the same coordinates and put the data of two or more places in the popup.The second way is to use an additional plugin [Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup](https://ghybs.github.io/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup/examples/subGroup-markercluster-controlLayers-realworld.388.html) See how it is resolved here [justjoin.it](https://justjoin.it/offers/stepwise-senior-java-kotlin-developer)